# Can Google Earth API be used without internet connection?

Tags: linux, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

http://en.opensuse.org/Google_Earth

This unlike Google maps needs to be installed on the computer.
If I get the map somehow on my harddisk, will I be able to use the Google Earth API without internet?

Comment: Good luck "getting" the map on you harddisk. Should be some hundreds of terabytes.

Comment: +1 for "Think Different" question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this is *technically* feasible, I think the answer is "no," because the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1) say that

> **9. License Requirements.** Google's licenses above are subject to your adherence to the following requirements:
>
> 9.1 Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation.
>
> 9.1.1 General Rules.
>
> (b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not operate (i) only behind
>                 a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal network (except during the development and testing
>                 phase); or (iii) in a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).

Therefore, enabling use the API without an internet connection violates the TOS.

Comment: But the quote also says: `(except during the development and testing
phase);` so it would be illegal for us to use it for commercial purpose only? :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only if the area you want to access is cached in the hard disk. You can cache places by using these steps:

1.At First explore your maximum intresting places  in google earth online,which you have to see even in offline system.

2.Copy the corresponding cache of which you have explored in the following location.(Copy icons folder, dbcache.dat, dbcache.dat.index ,dbroot_cache)
 "C:\Documents and Settings*username*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\GoogleEarth"

3.Install any Google Earth offline installers.

4.Update registry key and vid of google earth in the following location.

1.Open Run in the Start and then type "regedit"

2.go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER..Click on the + cross bar beside HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

3.Go to Software\ Google\Google Earth Plus..then u will seen list of registry keys beside.. go to Key right   click on that press modify and then enter any 12 digit number say better key="000000000000" and press ok and     VID="AAAACjYuMS4wLjUwMDE="

5.Paste the  Cache , in the offline system in the below path, i,e. "C:\Documents and Settings*username*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\GoogleEarth".

Comment: I would be grateful if you could post how to do all this in Linux.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how linux stores cache etc. in linux, so can't help you with that.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but i am curious to know what exactly you mean by "Google Earth offline installers" I'm not aware of any of these... Thanks in advanced